# Store binary relations

Tags: oracle

Let us we have university library database. We need to store data about books and keep track of what departments use each book. It needs to write simple requests to obtain number of departments that use given book and names of these departments.

I have several solution, but they seem to me non-sql style solutions.. For example, I store each record of book as values `(title,author,pages,MATH_DEPT_USE,CS_DEPT_USE, ... )`

where `MATH_DEPT_USE` and others like this takes value `0` (does not use) or value `1` (does use)

For example, `('Functional Analysis','Walter Rudin',510,1,0, ...)`

What the best way to store such kind of data ?

Answer (score 1):

A traditional approach would not store "*_USE" data at all, as it could too easily become inaccurate (it is derived, not inherent).

Rather, a table of books, a table of departments, and a relationship table of some kind to link them. The relationship could also include a `last_used` property that would let you understand how recently a department had used a book, for example.

You would then use SQL to link the tables (derive the use from the relationships) to create reports showing which departments used a particular book, or which books were used by a particular department, and when. – [pmdba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/203074/pmdba)

---

The columns 'MATH_DEPT_USE,CS_DEPT_USE' are a design flaw. You do not want those columns in a table that describes the entity 'BOOKS'.

You need a separate table for DEPARTMENTS, then for the many-to-many relationship, a 'link' table that has just the `book_id` and `dept_id` for every book-and-department combination.

You don't need a 'used/not used' indicator—the existence of a row in the link table indicates 'used'. – [EdStevens](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/83595/edstevens)